# Android button background disappearing

Tags: android, button, styles

I added a new style to my android styles.xml and it seems to have mysteriously (to me) affected another style.  Here's the xml

```
<style name="ToolbarBtnStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/btn_text</item>
    <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dip</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">54dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>

<style name="BtnStyle">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/btn_text</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn</item>
</style>
```

The BtnStyle style has been working fine for me.  However, after adding the ToolbarBtnStyle, the background of the BtnStyle disappears (this is the @drawable/btn image).

The culprit seems to be the background of the ToolbarBtnStyle.  I want it to be transparent so I set it to #00000000.  This causes the other button style's image to disappear.  If I make the ToolbarBtnStyle's background #FF000000 then the BtnStyle's background returns.

I either have a fundamental misunderstanding about how these styles interact or this seems to be a bug in the Android style stuff.  Any thoughts as to what could be going on?

Comment: Interestingly, if I set the ToolbarBtnStyle background to a transparent image rather than a transparent color, the button background on the BtnStyle return as well.  This is a work around at least.

Comment: what are the view hierarchies, i think posting the xml should make it better.